# Case Insenstive URLs with friendly url extension hiding. .htm and .html

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

How to redirect uppercase urls/links to lower case files with a modrewrite at the same time preserve the friendly urls (hiding .html and .htm) on my website?

Currently using the following rewrite rule to hide the .htm and .html files on my website:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.htm -f
RewriteRule !.*\.htm$ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.htm [L]
```

The goal is to preserve friendly url rule function above but at same time redirect all urls in my site that have uppercase characters in the file name portion of url to the actual file name which is always lowercase letters.  for example several links with uppercase letters including in file name look like this:
`http://sub.domain.com/dir1/100007ABCD`  but want the final url to resolve for search engines like this: `http://sub.domain.com/dir1/100007abcd`

my current static file names include the **.htm** extension like this: `http://sub.domain.com/dir1/100007abcd.htm`

In addition: The new rule needs to also rewrite all .html files to friendly on the website, as i have both .htm and .html files (which currentl rule handles both now), but the .html files don't need to be redirected to lowercase urls

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the rewrite map using [Apache's internal **tolower** function](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/rewrite/rewritemap.html#int). This can only be done in vhost or server config, and will result in an error if you try to put these directives in an htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteMap lowercase int:tolower
```

Then, in your htaccess file, you can use something like this **above any rewrite rules you already have**. The redirect rules must be applied before whatever rules you use for friendly url stuff:

```
# check that the lower case version of the URI is different than the unchanged URI
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /([^/]+)$
RewriteCond ${lowercase:%1}::%1 !^(.*)::\1$
RewriteRule ^(?:(.+/)|)(.*)$ /$1${lowercase:$2} [L,R=301]
```

This will redirect any requested URI whose last pathnode (the very last part of the `/A/B/C` path, e.g. the **C**) has an upper case letter. I'll explain what these rules do:

- `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /([^/]+)$`: This condition simply extracts the last pathnode into a backreference, to be later used by the `%1`
- `RewriteCond ${lowercase:%1}::%1 !^(.*)::\1$`: This condition takes the previously extracted pathnode, creates a string that is the all lower case pathnode, a `::` and the pathnode. The regular expression assumes that the lower cased version **is different** than the unmodified version. This means that there's an uppercase letter in the last pathnode.
- `RewriteRule ^(?:(.+/)|)(.*)$ /$1${lowercase:$2} [L,R=301]`: This rule only gets applied when the previous 2 conditions are met. It extracts the last pathnode (represented by the `$2` backreference) and everything, if any, before it (represented by the `$1` backreference). Then it calls the "lowercase" function on the last pathnode and 301 redirects the browser.

Comment: My server admin added the following as custom rule directly to Apaache RewriteMap, which now made the files case-insensitive, but will not redirect to lowercase. Here is the custom code that was added directly to RewriteMap on Apache if anyone has use for it as it does work: 

RewriteMap tolowercase int:tolower
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ${tolowercase:$1}

I will contact admin to adjust apache RewriteMap as you suggested and test your rules. Thank you.